# reactive input vector is strangely using quotes in shiny modules

Tags: input, module, shiny, quotes

*Prerequisites:* Shiny App using a module that contains a UI Output. The UI output itself contains any input (e.g. `textInput`). All IDs (of UIOutput and of Input) are generated using `ns()`

*Observations:* my `input` Vector is internally saved with Quotes. That would be no problem but prevents me from using the input in javascript (in `conditionalInput(condition='input.myModule-myInputtest=="someText"')`). How can I achive that `input$'mymodule'` is called `input$myModule`? Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance and best regards

[image: app screenshot]

Minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fixedPage(
  h2("Module example"), myModuleUI("myModule"), verbatimTextOutput("summary")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(myModule, "myModule", stringsAsFactors=F)
  output$summary <- renderPrint({ reactiveValuesToList(input) })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)

myModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("myInput"))
}
myModule <- function(input, output, session, stringsAsFactors) {
   output$myInput <- renderUI({ textInput(ns("myInputtest"), "A Text Input") })
 }
```

Comment: comment: this is probably always the case when an ID is using "-". When I change my uiOutput as `textInput("myModule-myInput", "A Text Input")`, the problem is persisting. So this is intended by shiny? Is there a workaround?

Comment: This is an R feature. Like in all R code, if you need to use a non-standard argument or variable name (e.g. one that includes dashes), you will also need to use backticks around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I think this is something other people would encounter.

Using the input in javascript (i.e. in a conditionPanel condition) is possible via `input['myModule-myInputtest']`, instead of the dot notation that can be used in situations without shiny modules.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

*Use tagList() inside myModuleUI

*Do not use ns() inside myModule

**Note**:

ns() concatenates id from callModule() with any string passed to it. For instance **ns("myInputtest")** gives **"myModule-myInputtest"**

```
library(shiny)

## Module UI ----
myModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  # taglist should be added here
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("myInput"))
  )
}

## Module Server ----
myModule <- function(input, output, session, stringsAsFactors) {
  output$myInput <- renderUI({ 
    textInput("myInputtest",
              "A Text Input") 
  })
}

## UI ----
ui <- fixedPage(
  h2("Module example"),
  myModuleUI("myModule"),
  verbatimTextOutput("summary")
)

## Server ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(myModule, "myModule", stringsAsFactors=F)
  output$summary <- renderPrint({reactiveValuesToList(input)})
}

# Run the application ---------------------------------------------------------
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: But the Input ID should be modularized, i.e. in the namespace of myModule - otherwise I need to keep track of alle InputIDs in my app so that none is called "myInputtest". The solution here is to call `session$ns("myInputtest")` instead of just ns(). The use of `tagList` is not needed for functionality, just when more than 1 tags are given. I think the quotes are intended, but my workaround was to use the list selector (`input['myModule-myInputtest']`)in javascript and conditionalPanel.

Answer (score 0):

You found a very interesting edge case. Luckily, there's a another way to access `input` children, as you already discovered (use square brackets, instead of dots). For anyone who may stumble upon this in the futre, here's a minimal working example, including the conditional panel:

```
library(shiny)

myModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("myInput")),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input['myModule-myInputtest'] === 'hello'",
      # condition = "console.log(input['myModule-myInputtest'])",   # useful for debugging
      sliderInput(ns("breakCount"), "Break Count", min=1, max=1000, value=10)
    )
  )
}
myModule <- function(input, output, session, stringsAsFactors) {
  output$myInput <- renderUI({
    textInput(session$ns("myInputtest"), "A Text Input") 
  })
}

ui <- fixedPage(
  h2("Module example"), 
  myModuleUI("myModule"), 
  verbatimTextOutput("summary")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(myModule, "myModule", stringsAsFactors=F)
  output$summary <- renderPrint({ reactiveValuesToList(input) })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```